# Windows 8 Store app (Xaml) save settings

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I create setting page with [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh872190.aspx). There are one TextBox. Value not saved in app. How save value on close settings?

```xml
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource SettingsFlyoutSectionStyle}">
        <TextBlock x:Uid="SiteUrl" Text="SiteUrl" Width="250"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="SiteUrl" Width="250"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Application.LocalSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings) (or `RoamingSettings`):

```
// Save
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["SiteUrl"] = SiteUrl.Text;

// Load
SiteUrl.Text = (string)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["SiteUrl"];
```

Comment: No auto-save in android?

Comment: @user3540246, what are you talking about? what does this have to do with android?

Comment: On android any fields from setting form (preferences) automatic save in local strorage. I think in xaml auto-save present too.

Comment: @user3540246, no, there is no such feature in XAML apps.